# How to collect and return multiple functions from a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Main.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useRectangleControls } from "src/useRectangleControls";

export function Main() {
    const rectangleRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const mainControls = useRectangleControls(rectangleRef);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(mainControls.isMouseInRectangle);
    }, [mainControls.isMouseInRectangle]);

    return (
        <div className="w-full h-screen flex items-center justify-center">
            <div className="w-[60%] h-[30%] bg-green-900" ref={rectangleRef} onMouseEnter={mainControls.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={mainControls.onMouseLeave}></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The above component returns a rectangle. The color of the rectangle depends on the mouse position. The event handlers for `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` were shifted to a custom hook called useRectangleControls:

```
import React from "react";

export function useRectangleControls(rectangleRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) {
    const [isMouseInRectangle, setIsMouseInRectangle] = React.useState(false);

    function onMouseEnter() {
        if (rectangleRef.current) {
            setIsMouseInRectangle(true);
            rectangleRef.current.classList.remove("bg-green-900");
            rectangleRef.current.classList.add("bg-red-900");
        }
    }
    function onMouseLeave() {
        if (rectangleRef.current) {
            setIsMouseInRectangle(false);
            rectangleRef.current.classList.remove("bg-red-900");
            rectangleRef.current.classList.add("bg-green-900");
        }
    }


    return { onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, isMouseInRectangle };
}
```

I want to collect all functions and return them in one variable. I want the return statement to look something like this: `return {rectangleControls, isMouseInRectangle}` where `rectangleControls` contains all functions inside the `useRectangleControls` custom hook.

My goal is to avoid updating the return statement each time I add a new function to `useRectangleControls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the following way

```
    import React from "react";
    
    export interface Indexable<T = any> {
      [key: string]: T|undefined;
    }
     export interface RectangleControls {
          onMouseEnter: () => void;
          onMouseLeave: () => void;
      }
            
            export function useRectangleControls(rectangleRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>) {
                const [isMouseInRectangle, setIsMouseInRectangle] = React.useState(false);
//           const rectangleControls: Indexable = {}; // one approach for typescript
const rectangleControls: RectangleControls = {
   onMouseEnter: () => {},
   onMouseLeave: () => {}
}; // second approach for typescript
         
            
                 rectangleControls.onMouseEnter = () => {
                    if (rectangleRef.current) {
                        setIsMouseInRectangle(true);
                        rectangleRef.current.classList.remove("bg-green-900");
                        rectangleRef.current.classList.add("bg-red-900");
                    }
                }
                rectangleControls.onMouseLeave = () => {
                    if (rectangleRef.current) {
                        setIsMouseInRectangle(false);
                        rectangleRef.current.classList.remove("bg-red-900");
                        rectangleRef.current.classList.add("bg-green-900");
                    }
                }
            
            
                return { rectangleControls, isMouseInRectangle };
            }
```

Edit: Explaining the changes made in the hook.
Here I have created an Object rectangleControls and converted the onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave to arrow function and assign them as key to  rectangleControls, this will help you achieve what you are looking for exporting a single variable.

Comment: This feels like the right answer except that in typescript I get this error: Property 'onMouseEnter' does not exist on type '{}'. and same one for onMouseLeave

Comment: Added an Indexable interface, which might help you.

Comment: This solves the error but I lose the vscode intellisense when I try to invoke mainControls.rectangleControls.onMouseEnter on Main.tsx

Comment: I have Edited the Answer please check, if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to import your custom hook `useRectangleControls` inside the component where you're going to use it. then use the `onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, isMouseInRectangle` from it like so.

```
const { onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, isMouseInRectangle } = useRectangleControls(pass your params here);
```

don't forget to import it from its location.

for example:

```
import useRectangleControls from "./hooks/useRectangleControls";
```

That's it.

Comment: I don't want to explicitly return every single function. I want to group all functions inside one variable and return that variable only

Comment: Aha, I see. I don't know tbh.